# composite identifier, but uses an ID generator other than manually assigning + Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three tables.

`item` with fields

```
    PK id
    title
    description
    type
    created
    delete
    fk user_id
```

`article` with fields

```
    PK item_id (one-to-one with item table), 
    body
```

`media` with fields

```
    PK id
    FK item_id (many-to-one with item table)
    url
    type
    mimetype
    isexternal
```

The `type` field in `article` table is an ENUM with values `ITEM, ARTICLE and IMAGE`.
The entities are autogenerated. So, originally the Article Entity doesn't extends the Item Entity. I had to change that.

I always get this error:

```
Entity 'Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Article' has a composite identifier 
but uses an ID generator other than manually assigning (Identity, Sequence). 
This is not supported.
```

**UPDATE:**
After deleting my type variable and fixing the discriminatormap I get this error:

```
Property Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Item::$type does not exist
```

This is my updated Item Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="item", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_item_user1_idx", columns={"user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "ITEM"="Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Item",
 *     "ARTICLE"="Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Article",
 *     "IMAGE"="Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Media"
 * })
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted;

    /**
     * @var \Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set deleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $deleted
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setDeleted($deleted)
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDeleted()
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

This is my updated Article Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article extends Item
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * Set body
     *
     * @param string $body
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get body
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me the error (internet didn't help me much).. And why do I get this error?

**P.S.**: I'm using Symfony 2.4.1 and PHP 5.4.20

Comment: what database platform are you using? this is more doctrine that symfony

Comment: I'm using a MySQL Database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this line (in `Item`):

```
/**
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"ITEM"="Item", "ARTICLE"="Article" "IMAGE"="Media"})
 */
```

should be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"ITEM"="Item", "ARTICLE"="Article", "IMAGE"="Media"})
 *                                                          ^
 */
```

I'm not really sure, but it could be that the discriminator map needs fully qualified classnames:

```
/**
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "ITEM"="Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Item",
 *     "ARTICLE"="Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Article",
 *     "IMAGE"="Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Media"
 * })
 */
```

Next you will need to remove the property `$type` from `Item`, because `type` is already used as discriminator column.

You might also want to use the console to validate your mappings:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

Fix all errors that might be reported.

**update**

> Property Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Item::$type does not exist

This means that somewhere in the code the (now non-existent) property `$type` of class `Item` is still being used. You'll have to track down where.

- Search your code for `->type`.
- Clear the cache (delete the content of the `app/cache` folder and run `app/console cache:clear`.

Comment: When I fix my DiscriminatorMap and delete my type variable + getter/setter and validate my schema I get: Property Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Item::$type does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I think that you planed Item::$type attribute while generating doctrine as a inheritance attribute. But this is also created by annotation:

`@ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")`

You have part of a table key and field with the same name. Try to remove class attribute (and getter, setter method), then update schema

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

After this change your classes works like a charm on my box

Good Luck!

Comment: When I try to update I get: property Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Item::$type does not exist

Comment: I see that you updated Item entity and now it is missing
` * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")`
leave annotation but remove variable $type

And now you have two @ORM\DiscriminatorMap annotations. Remove one, I relay not sure witch one is working in your class

Comment: Can you describe when you have this error? I have copy-paste your code and still it is working fine. Maybe I miss some behavior or action you perform. On the other hand when I use doctrine:schema:validate all I can see that `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\User")` is missing inversedBy declaration. Thats all.

Comment: One more thing: Please post Symfony and php versions.

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.4.1 and PHP 5.4.20

Comment: Ok, I have run this under Symfoy 2.4.1 your code work fine. Error that you posted `Property Beachteam\BeachteamBundle\Entity\Item::$type does not exist` means that you use this attribute somewhere in your code. Try to find `->type`. I'm sure that you find call to Item::$type attribute and when you delete it, code will run.